# Linq syntax to select nested objects

Tags: .net, linq

I'm trying to filter an IEnumerable using some of its nested properties.

I've racked my brain every which way but cannot find a solution to this query. In fact I don't event know whether this is possible.

Its structure is like this

**T** is a **Deal**
a **Deal** has a collection of **Subcategories** (the collection may be empty)
a **Subcategory** has a **SubcategoryId**

I want to be able to select Deals whether they have a SubcategoryId = parameter that is passed to method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Deal> FindDeals(IEnumerable<Deal> source, int subCategoryId)
{    
    return source.Where(d => d.Subcategories.Any(s => s.Id == subCategoryId));
}
```

Comment: Can't believe been ,essing around with SelectMany for hours

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) to pick deals where *any* of the subcategories is the one you want:

```
var foo = deals.Where(deal => deal.Subcategories.Any(sc => sc.Id == parameter));
```

Note that this is fine if `deal.Subcategories` is an *empty* collection - but if it's a null reference, instead, that would blow up, and you'd need:

```
var foo = deals.Where(deal => deal.Subcategories != null &&
                              deal.Subcategories.Any(sc => sc.Id == parameter));
```

... or fix it so that `deal.Subcategories` *is* never null, which would be generally preferable :)

Comment: Jon, sorry beaten to the post, but +1 for the null catch

Comment: Sorry John, Lee got there first with the answer

Comment: @user1437135: Not according to the timestamps (09:53:38 vs 09:53:41) - but it really doesn't matter. It's up to you which answer you accept; I'd accept the *better* answer rather than the *earlier* answer, and which answer you consider to be better is entirely your choice. It's really not a problem.

Comment: Think there could be a issue here then Jon as Lee's answer is showing up earlier in my list. I agree with you about the better answer entirely but Lee answered the question as I'd asked it. In this instance I only needed to validate an empty collection, but the tip you gave is great and will be useful elsewhere for me.